# determine location iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

from what i read i understand that iPhone can determine your location using Wi-Fi. If you're not in range of any Wi-Fi, iPhone can determine your location using cellular towers.

I am currently develop app that use the GPS so my question is when there is no GPS signal (like in buildings)does the location services try automatic to determine the position through Wifi or cellular towers OR i need to do somthing manualy in the code??

if it does automatic does it return a GPS format(latitude, longtitude) or somthing else?

thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return a position as always, but with reduced accuracy.

Comment: Not necessarily; not all cell towers might give out position information. If there is no GPS reception, no Wifi and uncooperative cell towers, then you will get no (new) position data. You will get the location of the last known fix, with that timestamp, so you can always check that the data isn't too old when you receive it.